# joining two panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble merging these two dataframes to give the expected results. I would like to check both dataframes and if column 1 and 3 of dataframe 1 match column 0 and 2 of dataframe 2 then return the last dataframe.

```
df1                 
0   1       2        3       4    5
4   4133    43  192.168.0.1 dt1 default
5   4134    43  192.168.0.2 dt2 t2
6   4135    43  192.168.0.3 dt3 t3


df2                 
0       1        2       3     4         5
4134    43  192.168.0.2 dt2 t2  
4136    43  192.168.0.4 dt4 default 
4137    43  192.168.0.5 dt5 default 



result                  
0    1       2       3       4   5
5   4134    43  192.168.0.2 dt2 t2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this using an inner join with `merge`:

```
df1[['1','3']].merge(df2, left_on=['1','3'], right_on=['0','2'], suffixes=('_x',''))\
              .drop(['1_x','3_x'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['1', '3'], right_on=['0', '2'])
```